# InspectUrlIndexRequest using the Google API PHP SDK giving an undefined call error

Tags: php, google-api

I am trying to access the inspect function for URL inspection by the SearchConsole API and keep getting an a Notice for Undefined property: Google\Service\SearchConsole::$index

```
$client = new Google\Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig(PATHT/TO/CREDS);
        $client->setApplicationName(NAME);
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly");
        $client->authenticate($accessToken);
        $service = new SearchConsole($client);
        $queryRequest = new InspectUrlIndexRequest();
        $queryRequest->setInspectionUrl(URL);
        $queryRequest->setSiteUrl(SITE URL);
        $response = $service->index->inspect;
```

It just seems to now know the function exists, tried variants, but looking at the source code, can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Solved for anyone who breaks something on their head trying:

```
$service->urlInspection_index->inspect
```

It's 'urlInspection_index' not 'index' as per the docs.